# How can I fix sorting of glossaries for capital and non-capital letters?

Tags: symbols, glossaries, sorting

I am currently making a list of symbols using the glossaries package. I have adjusted several parameters to fit the lay-out to my liking but in the process the sorting of glossaries has been altered. It now sorts:

capital letters -> Greek letters -> non-capital letters

instead of the desired:

capital letters -> non-capital letters -> Greek letters

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
\begin{longtable}{lp{1.5\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
 %
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline}}

%abbreviations
\newacronym{tes}{TES}{thermal energy storage}

%symbols
\newglossaryentry{tau}
{name={\ensuremath{\tau_{s}}},
description={Shear modulus}, unit={\ensuremath{MPa}}}

\newglossaryentry{hf}
{name={\ensuremath{H_{f}}},
description={Heat of fusion}, unit={\ensuremath{kJ/kg}}}

\newglossaryentry{r}
{name={\ensuremath{r}},
description={Radius}, unit={\ensuremath{m}}}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

\setglossarysection{section}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\printglossary[style=symbunitlong,title=List of Symbols]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]

I use \gls{tes} to have \gls{tau},\gls{hf} and \gls{r}.

\end{document}
```

**Current output:**

[image: Output of MWE with incorrect sorting]

How can I fix the sorting of glossaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't used the `sort` key, the sort value is taken from the `name` field which contains commands, but `makeindex` doesn't recognise LaTeX commands. It just sees a sequence of characters:

- `\` `e` `n` `s` `u` `r` `e` `m` `a` `t` `h`  (space) `{` `H` `_` `{` `f` `}` `}`
- `\` `e` `n` `s` `u` `r` `e` `m` `a` `t` `h`  (space) `{` `\` `t` `a` `u`  (space) `_` `{` `s` `}` `}`
- `\` `e` `n` `s` `u` `r` `e` `m` `a` `t` `h`  (space) `{` `r` `}`

These all start with a non-letter (`\`) so `makeindex` uses a simple character code comparison when sorting. Each sort value here starts with the same substring `\ensuremath {` so it's the character following this substring that determines the relative order:

- `H` (character code 0x48 = 72)
- `\` (character code 0x5C = 92)
- `r` (character code 0x72 = 114)

So the resulting order is `\ensuremath {H_{f}}` < `\ensuremath {\tau _{s}}` < `\ensuremath {r}`.

You need to use the `sort` key to change this order. If you want case-sensitive letter ordering (so that all the capitals come before lower case) then the `sort` key will still need to start with a non-letter. The best thing to do is to select non-letter prefixes that will ensure your desired order.

For example, `<` has character code 0x3C = 60 and `>` has character code 0x3E = 62, so any sort value that starts with `<` will come before any that start with `>`:

```
\newglossaryentry{tau}
{name={\ensuremath{\tau_{s}}},
sort={>tau},
description={Shear modulus}, unit={\ensuremath{MPa}}}

\newglossaryentry{hf}
{name={\ensuremath{H_{f}}},
sort={<Hf},
description={Heat of fusion}, unit={\ensuremath{kJ/kg}}}

\newglossaryentry{r}
{name={\ensuremath{r}},
sort={<r},
description={Radius}, unit={\ensuremath{m}}}
```

This will now produce the ordering `<Hf` < `<r` < `>tau`. You may prefer to define custom commands that automatically forms the `sort` from the label, but since all the labels are lower case, this would need another prefix (say, `=` character code 0x3D) for the lower case version. For example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[acronyms,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
\begin{longtable}{lp{1.5\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
 %
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline}}

\makeglossaries

%abbreviations
\newacronym{tes}{TES}{thermal energy storage}

% syntax: \newgreeksymbol[options]{label}{name}{description}{unit}
\newcommand{\newgreeksymbol}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#3},sort={>#2},description={#4},unit={#5},#1}%
}

\newcommand{\newsymbol}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#3},sort={=#2},description={#4},unit={#5},#1}%
}

\newcommand{\newSymbol}[5][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}{name={#3},sort={<#2},description={#4},unit={#5},#1}%
}

%symbols

\newgreeksymbol{tau}{\ensuremath{\tau_{s}}}{Shear modulus}{\ensuremath{MPa}}

\newSymbol{hf}{\ensuremath{H_{f}}}{Heat of fusion}{\ensuremath{kJ/kg}}

\newsymbol{r}{\ensuremath{r}}{Radius}{\ensuremath{m}}

\begin{document}

\setglossarysection{section}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\printglossary[style=symbunitlong,title=List of Symbols]
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title={List of Abbreviations}]

I use \gls{tes} to have \gls{tau},\gls{hf} and \gls{r}.

\end{document}
```

[image: image of document]

If you're interested, here's a completely different approach. Create a file called, say, `abbrvs.bib` that contains the abbreviations:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8
@abbreviation{tes,
  short = {TES},
  long = {thermal energy storage}
}
```

Create a file called, say, `syms.bib` that contains the symbols:

```
% Encoding: UTF-8

@symbol{tau,
  name={\ensuremath{\tau_{s}}},
  description={Shear modulus},
  unit={\ensuremath{MPa}}
}

@symbol{hf,
  name={\ensuremath{H_{f}}},
  description={Heat of fusion},
  unit={\ensuremath{kJ/kg}}
}

@symbol{r,
  name={\ensuremath{r}},
  description={Radius},
  unit={\ensuremath{m}}
}
```

The document is now:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[record,abbreviations]{glossaries-extra}

\glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}

\newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
\setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
\renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
\begin{longtable}{lp{1.5\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
{\end{longtable}}%
 %
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
\bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
\hline
\endhead}
\renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
& \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
& \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline}}

%abbreviations
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
   src={abbrvs},% definitions in abbrvs.bib
   save-locations=false % no number list required
]

%symbols
\GlsXtrLoadResources[
  src={syms},% definitions in syms.bib
  save-locations=false, % no number list required
  sort-field={name},
  sort=letter-case
]

\begin{document}

\setglossarysection{section}
\setglossarystyle{super}
\printunsrtglossary[style=symbunitlong,title=List of Symbols]
\printunsrtglossary[type=abbreviations,title={List of Abbreviations}]

I use \gls{tes} to have \gls{tau},\gls{hf} and \gls{r}.

\end{document}
```

If the document is called `myDoc.tex` then the build process is:

```
pdflatex myDoc
bib2gls myDoc
pdflatex myDoc
```

This produces:

[image: image of document]

If you check the [`bib2gls`](https://ctan.org/pkg/bib2gls) transcript file (`myDoc.glg`) you should find:

```
texparserlib: {}\ensuremath{\tau_{s}} -> s
texparserlib: {}\ensuremath{H_{f}} -> Hf
texparserlib: {}\ensuremath{r} -> r
```

This shows the sort values that `bib2gls` uses. The sort method was set to `letter-case` which again just uses a character code comparison but now `\tau` is interpreted as the character  (U+1D70F) which puts it after the lower case Latin characters.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented the first option and it works great. Just a small heads up: using \newsymbol might result in errors, as it did for me, so I suggest to use a different name to define that input.